# Can I add style and ng-style both for a single element?

Tags: angularjs, css, ng-style

I am setting style and ng-style for a single element for two different actions which is not working.

If I add both together it is not working. both are working separately

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="width:{{wide}}%;"  ng-style="{'color': (istrue()) ? 'red' : 'yellow' }"></div>
```

JS

```
$scope.wide = 50; // dynamic value
$scope.istrue = function () {
     var abc = true;
        if (abc) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: if you look in the developer tools, what does `<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="width:{{wide | l10n : 'number' }}%;"  ng-style="{'float': (isArrabic()) ? 'right' : 'none' }"></div>` resolve to?

Comment: <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" ng-style="{'float': (isArrabic()) ? 'right;' : 'none;' }" style="width:72%;"></div> when i add both...

Comment: can you add a minimal code snippet here so that we can check it being replicated

Comment: minimal code snippet???

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply styles byadding dynamic class name like below:

HTML

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="width:78%;" ng-class="isArrabic()"></div>
```

JS

```
$scope.wide = 78; // dynamic value
$scope.isArrabic = function () {
     var arabic = true;
        if (arabic) {
            return 'floatRight';
        }
        else {
            return 'floatLeft';
        }
     }
```

CSS:

```
.floatRight {
  float: right; 
  color: red;
}

.floatLeft {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I need to use this `isArrabic()` condition for different styles.. so Im returning true or flase